# Javascript - How do I map an array of objects to a datatable with column names?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-visualization

I have some data like this, an array of objects:

```js
source = [{
  day: 1,
  deliveries: 16,
  hours: 9
}, {
  day: 2,
  deliveries: 19,
  hours: 11
}]
```

Which I would like to have in this format:

```js
source = (['day', 'deliveries', 'hours'],
          ['1', '16', '9'],
          ['2', '19', '11'])
```

Sort of like a table. I read up a little on mapping arrays and tried this:

```js
const datatable = source.map(d => Array.from(Object.keys(d)))
console.log(datatable)
// [["day", "deliveries", "hours"], ["day", "deliveries", "hours"]]
```

And this:

```js
const datatable = source.map(d => Array.from(Object.values(d)))
console.log(datatable)
// [[1, 16, 9], [2, 19, 11]]
```

Each gives me half of what I want.
I tried this:

```js
let datatable = source.map(d => Array.from(Object.keys(d)))
let datatable2 = source.map(d => Array.from(Object.values(d)))

datatable = datatable[1]
let combined = datatable.concat(datatable2);
console.log(combined)
///["day", "deliveries", "hours", [1, 16, 9], [2, 19, 11]]
```

But even here the column names are not being combined correctly, and this way seems a little messy. How do I have the keys be on top (like column names would be) and the values following them?

Comment: What structure should the resulting datatable be? An array? (What you've shown for the "`source`" result, while syntactically valid, will result in `source` just being `['2', '19', '11']`.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder do you mean the resultant `source`? I am not sure what the kind of structure is called but I'm trying to transform my object from the original to what is [specified here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_preparing_data). Edit: I just read your answer too!

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant what structure do you want for `datatable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want `source` to be an array of arrays (common for table-like structures), get the keys once, then add each row array mapping the object's properties to the key for that index:

```
const keys = Object.keys(source[0]);
const result = [keys, ...source.map(obj => keys.map(key => obj[key]))];
```

Live Example:

```js
const source = [{
  day: 1,
  deliveries: 16,
  hours: 9
}, {
  day: 2,
  deliveries: 19,
  hours: 11
}];

const keys = Object.keys(source[0]);
const result = [keys, ...source.map(obj => keys.map(key => obj[key]))];
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Note that this assumes a couple of things:

1. The `source` array always has at least one object in it.
2. The objects in the `source` array all have the same set of properties.
3. You want the keys to be in the order in which they appear in the first object in the array. (JavaScript object properties *do* have a defined order now, but using that order is almost never a good idea, so you might want to do some kind of `sort` operation on `keys`.)

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Just use `[0]` to get the first item to get only keys. And then combine the array using `...`.

```js
let source = [{
  day: 1,
  deliveries: 16,
  hours: 9
}, {
  day: 2,
  deliveries: 19,
  hours: 11
}]

let ansArray = Object.keys(source[0]);
let datatable = source.map(d => Array.from(Object.values(d)))

let combined = [ansArray,...datatable];
console.log(combined);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array.from(Object.keys(d))` and `Array.from(Object.values(d))` will return the wrong data if the order of property is wrong.

```js
const source = [{
  day: 1,
  deliveries: 16,
  hours: 9
}, {
  day: 2,
  deliveries: 19,
  hours: 11
}]

const datatable = source.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
   if (index == 0) {
     acc.push(Object.keys(item));
   }
   const newRow = acc[0].reduce((rowAcc, prop) => {
     rowAcc.push(item[prop]);
     return rowAcc;
   }, []);
   
   acc.push(newRow);
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(datatable);
```